# Using python and urllib to get data from Yahoo FInance

Tags: python, urllib, stock

I was using urllib in python to get stock prices from yahoo finance. Here is my code so far:

```
import urllib
import re

name = raw_input(">")

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%s" % name)

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

# The problemed area 
regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_%s">(.+?)</span>' % name

pattern = re.compile(regex)

price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

print price
```

So I enter a value, and the stock price comes out. But so far I can get it to display a price, just a blank [ ]. I hace commented over where I believe the problem is. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Use [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing html/xml and not regex.

Comment: What value are you entering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not escaped the forward slash in your regex. Change your regex from:

```
<span id="yfs_l84_%s">(.+?)</span>
```

to

```
<span id="yfs_l84_goog">(.+?)<\/span>
```

This will fix your problem assuming you enter the company's listing code as the input to your code. Ex; goog for google.

That said, regex is a bad choice for what you are trying to do. As suggested by others, explore [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) which is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML. With BeautifulSoup your code can be as simple as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

name = raw_input('>')
url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}'.format(name)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
data = soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'yfs_l84_'.format(name)})
print data.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't use pandas? It has good support for financial data scraping and time series analysis.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

Here's the yahoo example straight from the documentation :

```
In [1]: import pandas.io.data as web
In [2]: import datetime
In [3]: start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
In [4]: end = datetime.datetime(2013, 01, 27)
In [5]: f=web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
In [6]: f.ix['2010-01-04']
Out[6]: 
OnOpen               10.17
High               10.28
Low                10.05
Close              10.28
Volume       60855800.00
Adj Close           9.75
Name: 2010-01-04 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get data from Yahoo Finance using python2 or python3 is by using a POST method.
You can easily test this out using a Rest service like Postman

Open up postman and use Method POST and use this
Then you will see the data.  Simply re-create this in python

```
import requests
url="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/GOOG? period1=1519938930&period2=1522354530&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=.tLvYBkGDu3"

response = requests.post(url)
print response.text
```

I used to get the data using urllib2 but it gives an authorization error now
They are probably filtering everything through Rest methods like GET and POST

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) will show you how to build Yahoo finance queries that will return csvs.  Then you can use the `csv` library to parse them easily.

If you really want to try hacking through the HTML, use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  HTML can't be parsed easily with regexes.